# Преобразовать значения в списке и заменить их

Tags: python

У меня есть файл со значениями температуры, где-то есть ошибки в виде того, что программа вместо реальной температуры пишет 300 Кельвин, нужно найти соседние значения температуры, взять их среднее и вставить обратно в список, чтобы вышел корректный график температуры.
Вот к примеру:
346
346
300
347
347
Здесь нужно взять среднее и вместо 300 подставить.
В моем коде он мне выдает только значение 304 и все, не могу понять почему

```
li = []
def FileOpener(): #Открываем файл для создания списка значений
    f = open('file.txt')
    for i in f:
        li.append(int(i))
    f.close()

FileOpener()

def Fixer():
    f = open('fixed.txt', 'w')
    a = [(li[i - 1] + li[i + 1])/2 for i in li if i == 300]
    print(a)
    f.close()
Fixer()
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: a = [(li[x - 1] + li[x + 1])/2 if i == 300 else i for x, i in enumerate(li)]